# Asset Catalog Xcode 6.1.1 Launch Image Portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need to put in Launch images for a portrait iPhone app.
Can anyone inform what does every of the following terms mean in Asset Catalog:

1. Ratina HD 5.5 (I think it is: 1242 x 2208 launch image for iPhone 6+)
2. Ratina HD 4.7 (I think it is: 750 x 1334 launch image for iPhone 6)
3. 2x (iPhone Portrait iOS 7, 8)
4. Ratina 4 (iPhone Portrait iOS 7, 8)
5. 1x (iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6)
6. 2x (iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6)
7. Ratina 4 (iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6)

Where to put the 640 x 1136 launch image?
What is the difference between point 4 and 7?

An Image for your reference:
[image: Snap shot of Asset Cataglog]

Answer (score 0):

The 320x568 launch image is to be kept in iPhone Portrait 1x & 2x

There isn't much difference between pots 4 & 7.

Retina 4 (iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6)

Retina 4 means your iPhone 5 splash screen of size 960x1136

Hope this helps..

Comment: Can anyone inform what does every of the following terms mean in Asset Catalog? Terms like: Ratina 4. A fully descriptive answer will everyone else coming to this question.

Comment: 3) 2x (iPhone Portrait iOS 7, 8) - means splash screen with double resolution. 640x9960
4) Retina 4 means retina splash screen for 4 inch screen i.e. iPhone 5.

5) 1x means simple splash screen with iPhone 4 non-retina resolution 320x480 

6) It means the splash screen with twice the resolution of 1x i.e. 640x960